# GatsbyJS with Firebase - WebpackError: ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined

Tags: firebase, webpack, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, gatsby

I'm received error with **gatsby develop**. It's very similar to this one: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2222, but I'm received error with **gatsby develop**, not with gatsby build. I did a lot of research but I can't find working solution.
At first I had a problem with **gatsby build**, like in this post: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2222, but I resolved it with custom onCreateWebpackConfig(you can find it below).

Stack: 
- Gatsby
- **Firebase(error probably with that)**
- Redux

I'm also delete .cache and node_modules and install everything again, but it didn't work.

**Error**:

```
There was an error compiling the html.js component for the development server.

See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help https://gatsby.dev/debug-html ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined
]);
  86 | 
> 87 | proxyRequestMethods(Index, '_index', IDBIndex, [
     | ^
  88 |   'get',
  89 |   'getKey',
  90 |   'getAll',

  WebpackError: ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined

  - idb.mjs:87 Module../node_modules/idb/lib/idb.mjs
    node_modules/idb/lib/idb.mjs:87:1

  - index.esm.js:1 Module../node_modules/@firebase/installations/dist/index.esm.js
    node_modules/@firebase/installations/dist/index.esm.js:1:1

  - index.esm.js:1 Module../node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/index.esm.js
    node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/index.esm.js:1:1

  - index.esm.js:1 Module../node_modules/firebase/analytics/dist/index.esm.js
    node_modules/firebase/analytics/dist/index.esm.js:1:1

  - index.ts:1 Module../src/firebase/index.ts
    src/firebase/index.ts:1:1

  - index.esm.js:32 emit
    node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/index.esm.js:32:1
```

**My gatsby-node file**:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions, getConfig }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      externals: getConfig().externals.concat(function(context, request, callback) {
        const regex = /^@?firebase(\/(.+))?/;
        if (regex.test(request)) {
          return callback(null, `umd ${request}`);
        }
        callback();
      }),
    });
  }
};
```

**My firebase dependencies:**

```
 "@firebase/firestore-types": "^1.10.1",
 "firebase": "^7.13.1",
 "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
 "firebase-functions": "^3.5.0",
 "firebase-tools": "^7.16.1",
```

**Firebase index file:**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/analytics';
const firebaseConfig = {...};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const storage = firebase.storage();
```

**Project repo**: https://github.com/olafsulich/Projecty

Post on Github issues: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2946

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following snippet will only work on `build` environment because of your condition (`stage === 'build-html'`):

```
   exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions, getConfig }) => {
      if (stage === 'build-html') {
        actions.setWebpackConfig({
          externals: getConfig().externals.concat(function(context, request, callback) {
            const regex = /^@?firebase(\/(.+))?/;
            if (regex.test(request)) {
              return callback(null, `umd ${request}`);
            }
            callback();
          }),
        });
      }
    };
```

Remove it and use it like this:

```
   exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions, getConfig }) => {
        actions.setWebpackConfig({
          externals: getConfig().externals.concat(function(context, request, callback) {
            const regex = /^@?firebase(\/(.+))?/;
            if (regex.test(request)) {
              return callback(null, `umd ${request}`);
            }
            callback();
          }),
        });
    };
```

---

> Thank's a lot! It's working only on gatbsy develop, but now when I
> want to build project, I get an error - TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'concat' of undefined. You know how to solve it?

Regarding the new issue, you can follow a workaround in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246333/how-to-initialize-firebase-in-gatsby), This is a common error in third-party modules in Gatsby when they try to reach a DOM element (usually `window`) that is not already defined when the app builds. So, you need to wait until `window` is defined. You can achieve this in two ways:

1. Instancing your firebase with a condition like this:

   ```
    import firebase from '@firebase/app';
    import '@firebase/auth';
    import '@firebase/firestore';
    import '@firebase/functions';

    const config = {
       ... firebase config here
    };

    let instance;

    export default function getFirebase() {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (instance) return instance;
        instance = firebase.initializeApp(config);
        return instance;
      }

      return null;
    }
   ```

   *Note the  `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` statement*
2. By ignoring firebase module in you webpack configuration like shows [their docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/). In your `gatsby-node.js`:

   ```
    exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
      if (stage === "build-html") {
        actions.setWebpackConfig({
          module: {
            rules: [
              {
                test: /bad-module/,
                use: loaders.null(),
              },
            ],
          },
        })
      }
    }
   ```

   *Replace `bad module` for firebase (or the package/folder name in `node_modules`). Leave the slashes since `test` is a regular expression rule*

   This snippet replaces your previous one that seems to throw an error in `concat()` function.

---

For those who wants to try the `concat()` resolution, this will be helpful too:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions, getConfig }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      externals: getConfig().externals.concat((context, request, callback) => {
        const regex = /^@?firebase(\/(.+))?/
        // exclude firebase products from being bundled, so they will be loaded using require() at runtime.
        if (regex.test(request)) {
          return callback(null, `commonjs ${request}`) // <- use commonjs!
        }
        callback()
      }),
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! It's working only on gatbsy develop, but now when I want to build project, I get an error - ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined```. You know how to solve it?

Comment: Thank you very much, I have to try it out. I will let you know about result

Answer (score 3):

Solved this problem!!
I'm using "gatsby": "^3.10.2", "firebase": "9.0.0-beta.6".

firebase needs to be set externals as `commonjs`.

`gatsby-node.js`:

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions, getConfig }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      externals: getConfig().externals.concat((context, request, callback) => {
        const regex = /^@?firebase(\/(.+))?/
        // exclude firebase products from being bundled, so they will be loaded using require() at runtime.
        if (regex.test(request)) {
          return callback(null, `commonjs ${request}`) // <- use commonjs!
        }
        callback()
      }),
    })
  }
}
```

Please try this setting.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: this bit `(context, request, callback)` made webpack throw a deprecation warning. Changing it to `{ context, request }, cb` fixed that warning.