# Resolve firebase authentication (google signIn) deploy error on netlify with gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, gatsby, netlify

Thank you It worked I am pushing my code. You can use it as a reference.

I am using firebase for my project to add google sign in in gatsby.
Locally it works fine but I can't seem to deploy it on netlify.

[My Git Repo](https://github.com/Mahmedabid/Contentful-Blog)

I have used gatsby-firebase-plugin but it gives me an error

```
Warning: This is a browser-targeted Firebase bundle but it appears it is being
12:19:15 AM: run in a Node environment. If running in a Node environment, make sure you
12:19:15 AM: are using the bundle specified by the “main” field in package.json.
12:19:15 AM: If you are using Webpack, you can specify “main” as the first item in
12:19:15 AM: “resolve.mainFields”:
12:19:15 AM: Resolve | webpack
12:19:15 AM: If using Rollup, use the @rollup/plugin-node-resolve plugin and specify “main”
12:19:15 AM: as the first item in “mainFields”, e.g. [‘main’, ‘module’].
12:19:15 AM: https://github.com/rollup/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve
12:19:15 AM: failed Building static HTML for pages - 0.624s
12:19:15 AM: error Building static HTML failed
12:19:15 AM:
12:19:15 AM:
12:19:15 AM: TypeError: Cannot read property ‘split’ of null
```

Even if I use separate file for firebase like

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.APP_ID
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();

export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

I get this error

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 0.823s
10:21:12 AM: error Building static HTML failed
10:21:12 AM: 
10:21:12 AM:   663 |  * limitations under the License.
10:21:12 AM:   664 |  */
10:21:12 AM: > 665 | registerFunctions(firebase, fetch.bind(self));
10:21:12 AM:       |                           ^
10:21:12 AM:   666 | firebase.registerVersion(name, version);
10:21:12 AM:   667 | //# sourceMappingURL=index.esm.js.map
10:21:12 AM:   668 |
10:21:12 AM: 
10:21:12 AM:   WebpackError: ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

I added GATSBY_ prefix before env variables
[image]

I also added environment variables in netlify environment
[image]

After adding null to avoid SSR breaking I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: The problem may be with the code ' WebpackError: ReferenceError: fetch is not defined'. have you imported fetch, or maybe you aren't using it as a global variable.

Comment: also, i dont see a reason to use firebase unless you're making a userbase. anyways, Check the code, see where 'fetch' is defined. It may be a package that hasn't been imported, or a local variable, make it a global one if so

Comment: How do I import fetch?

Comment: use this const fetch = require('node-fetch');

Comment: In gastby-node.js??

Comment: The fetch error is no longer appearing

Comment: When I added null to avoid SSR breaking

Comment: wherever you are calling registerFunctions(firebase, fetch.bind(self)) , in that file use it at the top

Comment: did it work bro?

Comment: I am pushing my changes

Comment: I think firebase is still undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231301/discussion-between-joel-company-and-ahmed-abid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload your environment variables to Netlify. In addition (and if you've done it), you will need to rename it to make it accessible to Netlify.

[image: Environment variables in Netlify]

Accessible at: https://app.netlify.com/sites/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/settings/deploys#environment

As I said, your project works perfectly locally but Netlify doesn't have access (yet) to those variables if you just upload it with the same naming. As you can see in [Netlify's docs about Gatsby](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/gatsby/#gatsby-build-plugin):

> Any [environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables) prefixed with `GATSBY_` are processed by
> Gatsby and made available in the browser for client-side JavaScript
> access. Visit the [Gatsby docs about environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) for more
> information.

You need to prefix all environment variables with `GATSBY_` to make them available. So all your references will became:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.GATSBY_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.GATSBY_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.GATSBY_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.GATSBY_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.GATSBY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.GATSBY_APP_ID
  };
```

Hence the environment files itself, both (`.env.development` and `.env.production`) will become:

```
GATSBY_API_KEY = 123
GATSBY_AUTH_DOMAIN = 123
GATSBY_PROJECT_ID = 123
GATSBY_STORAGE_BUCKET = 123
GATSBY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID = 123
GATSBY_APP_ID = 123
```

Now, Netlify will have access to your Firebase initialization and won't break the deployment.

Summarizing:

- Upload environment variables to Netlify with `GATSBY_` prefix
- Change all references to the previous environment variables. All variables you want to be readable by Netlify must be prefixed.

In addition, add the following snippet in the `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /firebase/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/29012

This will add a `null` loader to the firebase to avoid the SSR breaking.

Regarding the new issue:

> gatsby_plugin_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___ default(...).auth

It should be fixed by:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import '@firebase/functions';

const config = {
   ... firebase config here
};

let instance;

export default function getFirebase() {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    if (instance) return instance;
    instance = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    return instance;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Then, you just can:

```
import React { useEffect } from 'react';
import getFirebase from './firebase';

function MyApp() {
const firebase = getFirebase();

useEffect(() => {
if (!firebase) return;

// once your firebase is instanced, use it.
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { ... });
}, [firebase]);
}
```

Comment: Can you detail more about your answer? What have you tried? Have you cleaned the cache? Does it still build locally? As you can see in the documentation, the solution is this one. Renaming the environment variables to make them available by Netlify.

Comment: I've added a new snippet based on https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/29012 to avoid SSR breaking. The previous configurations needs to be kept (what we've done so far)

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592656/firebase-auth-is-not-a-function ? and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246333/how-to-initialize-firebase-in-gatsby

Comment: The key part is : typeof window !== 'undefined'

Comment: `if (!firebase) return;` wrap your logic when firebase is initalized

Comment: thanks it worked. I just had to access the first element of firebase object